Salesforce knowledge article images are storing on https://***.googleusercontent.com
When creating a knowledge article, there are two ways to upload images into the rich text editor:

Using the Upload Image Icon: You can click the image icon in the rich text editor, which opens a popup and provides an upload button. This allows you to upload an image directly from your computer (the image is uploaded to https://***.file.force.com).

Drag and Drop: You can also drag and drop an image directly into the rich text editor. However, when using this method, the image is uploaded to https://***.googleusercontent.com.


Issue:
When users drag and drop images, they are uploaded to the googleusercontent.com domain. This is causing a Content Security Policy (CSP) error, as CSP only allows resources (like images) to load from trusted or whitelisted domains. When accessing the article through customer support(experience cloud site), these images may be blocked due to the CSP restrictions.
Questions:

Why are images uploaded to googleusercontent.com when using drag and drop?

It seems that the drag-and-drop functionality defaults to using the browser's internal handling (Google Chrome's integration, for example), which uploads the image to googleusercontent.com(I'm not sure).



Any idea why it's storing on googleusercontent.com instead of file.force.com?
